# Issues in setting up a Gitolite server

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, gitolite

We are a group of developers working on an android project. I want to set up a GIT repository from my Ubuntu 14.04 machne. I followed the steps outlined here- https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html
I have successfully set up a gitolite server. I have progressed to switching to the git user and import the administrator's key into gitolite.However I get stuck up while executing the following command -

```
git clone git@$IP_ADDRESS:gitolite-admin.git
```

The system asks me for a GIT password. 
I need to know how to get the GIT password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Gitolite configuration section](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html#git-configuring-gitolite) **assumes that the current user is the repository administrator**.

So make sure that the user doing `git clone git@$IP_ADDRESS:gitolite-admin.git` has the private and public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`), with the public one being the one used `/tmp/$(whoami).pub` when doing the gitolite setup.

Note that the documentation uses '`gl-setup`', which is for gitolite v2 ([package gitolite for trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gitolite)).
Gitolite v2 is obsolete: use the latest clone of [`sitaramc/gitolite`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), and the [setup process described here (to be done as the git user)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#install).
(or use the [package gitolite3 for trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gitolite3))

Comment: gitolite3 for trusty works well. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.